# Calculating the maximum force on a large cantilevered round steel bar that is used to support a tree house

Tags: structural-engineering

Hi all and thanks for this page.

I have constructed a large treehouse across two trees. The main support is provided by passing a very large 57mm dia high tensile steel bolt through each tree. Each bolt is 1.5m in length. The seel used is 4140 rod.

I have placed 2 USB 200 steel beams on top of each end of the protruding bolt. This provides two parallel steel beams. These beams are well in excess of what is required.

My question is what is the maximum weight I can apply to the 57mm 4140 steel bolts.

ie what is the max force that can be applied to a 57mm cantilevered bolt, where the force is applied 400mm out from the tree

I have used F= S*(pi*d^3/32)/L
where
S= Sheer modulas 415MPa for 4140 steel
d = diameter 0.057m
L= distance from the tree trunk to the beam (400mm)

Comment: This what I have calculated so far S*(pi*d^3/32)/L
S=415MPa, d= 0.057m L=04m Comes to roughly 2 Ton force.

Comment: And what is your result?

Comment: Hi Solar Mike. I have calculated 2 ton at each of the ends ie 8 tons capacity. I'm interested to hear if I have used the correct approach to calculate this max load. I'm not an engineer BTW

Comment: What can a tree handle over the cross section of the bolt? What happens if one bolt breaks?

Comment: Hi Abel  I'm not concerned about the tree's strength, they are Australian hardwood. And my research shows that the trees will react to the additional weight by growing "encapsulating" the areas were the bolts pass through the outer layers of the tree. My question relates to the strength of the 4140 steel bolts. I believe these are the weak link in this project. Cheers David